# jQuery tag-it, how to execute post when item removed

Tags: javascript, jquery, tags, tag-it

I'm using the jQuery Tag-It script, can be viewed here:

http://levycarneiro.com/projects/tag-it/example.html

The script originally does not come with the option to send posts of the added tags or remove tags that the user removes.

I successfully added the post request to a php script so that when someone adds a tag, it inserts it in the DB.

The problem is, when someone clicks the 'x' button to remove one of the tags, I can't seem to find a way to get the actual tag value..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code modified so you can have access to the tag that gets removed..

In the `click` handler (*of the **x***)

```
if (e.target.tagName == 'A') {
            // Removes a tag when the little 'x' is clicked.
            // Event is binded to the UL, otherwise a new tag (LI > A) wouldn't have this event attached to it.
            var tag = $(e.target).parent();
            //console.log( tag.children('input').val() ); // this line extracts the tag value
            tag.remove();
        }
```

and in the `keypress` handler use

```
if (tag_input.val() == "") {
                // When backspace is pressed, the last tag is deleted.
                var tag = $(el).children(".tagit-choice:last");
                // console.log( tag.children('input').val() ); // this line extracts the tag value
                tag.remove();
            }
```

**Demo at** http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/yYHTu/1/